# SPARQL filter/aggregate results by subgraph

Tags: sparql, rdf, graph-theory, rdfs

I would like to write a query which filters out some results by using some other properties of the graph. I explain with this example.

I am modelling a permissions system. There are some subjects, resources and permissions. Subjects have certain permissions on resources. Some permissions imply other permissions. A simplified example with 3 permissions, and 3 resources that the single subject has one (two in one case) of those permissions on.

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX : <http://schema#>
PREFIX d: <http://data#>

INSERT DATA {

    :Permission rdf:type rdf:Property .

    :Read rdf:type rdf:Property ;
          rdfs:subPropertyOf :Permission .

    :Write rdf:type rdf:Property ;
           rdfs:subPropertyOf :Permission ;
           :implies :Read .

    :Admin rdf:type rdf:Property ;
           rdfs:subPropertyOf :Permission ;
           :implies :Write ,
                    :Read .

    d:s1 rdf:type :Subject .
    d:r1 rdf:type :Resource .
    d:r2 rdf:type :Resource .
    d:r3 rdf:type :Resource .

    d:s1 :Admin d:r1 .
    d:s1 :Read d:r1 .
    d:s1 :Write d:r2 .
    d:s1 :Read d:r3 .
}
```

I can easily write a query to see for a given subject, what the implied permissions are on some resources.

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX : <http://schema#>
PREFIX d: <http://data#>
SELECT DISTINCT ?subject ?resource ?implied (?permission AS ?implied_by)
WHERE {
    BIND(d:s1 AS ?subject)
    ?resource rdf:type :Resource .
    ?subject rdf:type :Subject .
    ?permission rdfs:subPropertyOf :Permission ;
                :implies* ?implied .

    ?subject ?permission ?resource .
}
```

This will give some results like:

```
+----------------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| subject        | resource       | implied             | implied_by          |
+----------------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| http://data#s1 | http://data#r1 | http://schema#Admin | http://schema#Admin |
| http://data#s1 | http://data#r1 | http://schema#Read  | http://schema#Admin |
| http://data#s1 | http://data#r1 | http://schema#Write | http://schema#Admin |
| http://data#s1 | http://data#r1 | http://schema#Read  | http://schema#Read  |
| http://data#s1 | http://data#r3 | http://schema#Read  | http://schema#Read  |
| http://data#s1 | http://data#r2 | http://schema#Write | http://schema#Write |
| http://data#s1 | http://data#r2 | http://schema#Read  | http://schema#Write |
+----------------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

**What I would like to do is write a query which only returns the minimum list of permissions per resource which imply all the others. Any ideas on how I would achieve this efficiently would be most welcome.** This seems a bit like a `MAX` aggregation, but where a graph is actually needed to determine the results. For example, the ideal results would be:

```
+----------------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| subject        | resource       | implied             | implied_by          |
+----------------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| http://data#s1 | http://data#r1 | http://schema#Admin | http://schema#Admin |
| http://data#s1 | http://data#r3 | http://schema#Read  | http://schema#Read  |
| http://data#s1 | http://data#r2 | http://schema#Write | http://schema#Write |
+----------------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Note that the data and queries are actually more complicated that this so it is absolutely necessary for me to use the parameter path even though I then want to get rid of most of the information it introduces.

```
?permission rdfs:subPropertyOf :Permission ;
                :implies* ?implied .
```

Note also that I thought of adding an integer value to each permission so that I could simply get the minimum value of this field, but my permission structure is not single rooted in reality, so sometimes this would not be appropriate.

**Effectively the question is how to remove any permissions (for a resource) which are implied by other results (for that resource)**

Comment: Possible duplicate of something... Basically, you need `FILTER NOT EXISTS {?subject ?implied_ ?resource . ?implied_ :implies+ ?implied}`.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of that. It's so obvious now you've told me! Thanks.